# gapi.auth.authorize with immediate: true is not working

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-cloud-endpoints, google-api-js-client

I'm trying to do Gmail Oauth.

When I call this function with **immediate:true**, still it's showing the popup window while authorizing.

Please let me know any mistake is there or not, also any alternative method.

```
gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true}, callbackAuthResult);
```

Here's my Code:

```
function signin(getAuthStatus) {

gapi.auth.authorize({
        'client_id': 'myID',
        scope: 'email', immediate: true
    },getAuthStatus);

}

function getAuthStatus() {
        gapi.client.Myendpoint.MyEndpointMethod().execute(function (resp) {
            console.log(resp);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, We have to understand how oauth process works,

In Google OAuth,

If **immediate** value is **false**, then browser will open up a popup, where people have to allow your application to get their details from Google.

If **immediate** value is **true**, then it'll be automatically authorized without any popup, where people don't have to allow the application.

Keep **immediate** value as **false**, while you are asking user to login to your application for the first time, then browser will open up popup and user will allow your application to get details. From next time onwards, wherever you are using OAuth to make authenticated calls in your application, put **immediate** value as **true**, because user already allowed your application, so you'll get user info directly without asking him for permissions again and again.